# Visual Studio (VS) 2019 16.6.0 Preview 1.0 iOS app Cannot open story board

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

I've been at this for about a week now and cannot get any suggestions out there to work.  I originally started this with VS 2017 and was getting this error when attempting to open a storyboard after creating a new project.  The steps I executed:

1. Opened VS 2017 15.9.21
2. Created a new project by clicking on File->New->Project
3. Selected iOS App (Xamarin)
4. Selected Single View App
5. Gave the project a name, created the project successfully
6. Paired with the macbook successfully
7. Attempted to open the Main.storyboard
8. After some time, I got the error: This file could not be upgraded to the correct format automatically and so cannot be opened. If Xcode is correctly configured then re-saving the file in Xcode may resolve the issue.

I then opened the same project with VS 2019 and attempted to open Main.storyboard, same error.  I updated all the mac components, IE; XCode and Visual Studio for the mac which generated a whole hosts of issues that I corrected over the last week, mostly pairing issues which I eventually resolved.  Now I am working in VS 2019 and I get the same exact error I was getting in VS 2017.  I went back to VS 2017 and tried again, after successfully pairing with the mac, to open Main.storyboard and got the same error.  So apparently it doesn't matter what version of VS I use, I can't open a storyboard.  I've tried everything that I've run accross out there and nothing works.  The last document I looked at was:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/#next-steps

I followed all the steps in this document exactly and still cannot open a storyboard.  Any one got any answers for this?

Comment: Hi , do you have a try with Visual Studio for Mac to create a new project to check whehter it works ? By the way , not using preview version of vs to check that . My local site is VS 2019 16.5.0 , and it works .

Comment: First time I try to open a storyboard on the mac, won't open, same error as on Windows.  I then open it in XCode no problem, then I can open it in VS for mac.  I have the latest version of VS 2019 Community on the mac.

Comment: UPDATE:
I had reported this problem to Microsoft as a bug, they just updated the issue saying it was fixed pending release.  Here's hoping ....

Comment: See my issue here:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/956064/this-file-could-not-be-upgraded-to-the-correct-for.html

Comment: Got it , looking forward to the next version of xamarin !

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found that the problem lies in the MAC.
Suddenly I could not open the Main.storyboard on my PC. For ANY projects!
So, I created a new project on the MAC and when opening up the Main.storyboard it failed also. Next, I did a Re Boot on the MAC and NOW I can open the Main.storyboard.
Also, in my fury and reckless attempts to fix the issue, I reinstalled VS2019 on my Windows Machine. However I'm pretty sure the problem was in the MAC getting corrupted somehow.
Note: I noticed when opening up the Main.storyboard on the PC it briefly showed "Connecting to the MAC', so I'm assuming if it fails on the MAC it will fail on the PC.

So how did this occur? I believe I tried to open the Main.storyboard on the PC before it was done connecting to the MAC. This somehow corrupt something in the MAC which required a reboot to heal. When all else fails 'Re-Boot'!

Cheers,

Todd